# creating an instance in a for loop

Tags: python, instance

I'm trying extract class names via dir() and create their instance on the fly via a variable name in a for loop. How can I make python interpret 'item' as a variable name and not the 'non-existing' class name.

```
>>> class cls1():
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.speak = 'say cls1'
...     def replay(self):
...         print self.speak
...
>>> for item in dir():
...     if item[:2] != '__':
...         print 'item = ', item
...         x = item()
...         x.reply()
...
item =  cls1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dir()` produces a sorted list of names; these are just strings. They are not references to the actual objects. You can't apply a call to a string.

Use the [`globals()` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) instead, this gives you a mapping with both the names and the actual objects:

```
for name, obj in globals().items():
    if not name.startswith('__'):
        print "name =", name
        instance = obj()
        instance.replay()
```

`dir()` at the module level, without arguments, essentially returns `sorted(globals())`.

Comment: Would like to ask you one more question then...isn't there a way in Python to evaluate a string into a class name. Maybe via eval?? In other words, I would think that this string can be matched against the class name and then be converted automatically into the reference. Thanks

Comment: @Kris: `eval` should only be used as a last resort. The `globals()` dictionary gives you a direct mapping from a string value to the object. If all you have is a string name in the variable `name`, then `globals()[name]` gives you the object.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify - your example worked above, all is good. Was just wondering about alternative (and less optimal) ways of  doing this. Thanks again.